# Rails: nested models disappearing after validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :case
  has_many :invoice_positions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_positions, allow_destroy: true
```

And i have a form createn with https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon but i have one small problem - after validation fails all invoice_positions disappears.

Here is part of form where i render positions:

```
<% f.fields_for :invoice_positions do |invoice_position| %>
            <%= render 'invoice_position_fields', f: invoice_position %>
        <% end %>
```

And my create action in controller:

```
def create
    @case = Case.find(params[:case_id])
    @invoice = Invoice.new(invoice_params)
    @invoice.case = @case

    if @invoice.save
      flash[:success] = 'Faktura zapisana'
      redirect_to case_case_invoices_path(@case)
    else
      @invoice.invoice_positions.build(params[:invoice_positions_attributes])
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Here are parameters from console:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"f1IUw+mt10QX3PFy4g1Hv+8VkD8sQR7roPKrh+6N4Va6Un2mGrR86/XR91hsRjI4V6FLNyavyc8TeGZt9E2RoQ==", "invoice"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2016", "date(2i)"=>"1", "date(3i)"=>"26", "pay_date(1i)"=>"2016", "pay_date(2i)"=>"2", "pay_date(3i)"=>"5", "city"=>"Rzeszów", "person"=>"Test Test", "comment"=>"", "invoice_positions_attributes"=>{"1453833757786"=>{"name"=>"dwqdwqdwq", "kind"=>"", "price"=>"", "quantity"=>"", "tax"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1453833759600"=>{"name"=>"wdqdwqqwd", "kind"=>"", "price"=>"", "quantity"=>"", "tax"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "case_id"=>"1"}
```

And here the invoice_position_fields view:

```
<tr class="nested-fields">
  <td>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Nazwa' %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= f.text_field :kind, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Typ (np. usł., szt.)' %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= f.text_field :price, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Cena jedn. netto' %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= f.text_field :quantity, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Ilość' %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= f.text_field :tax, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'VAT' %>
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <%= link_to_remove_association icon('trash'), f, {class: 'btn btn-danger'} %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Could you post the template code in invoice_position_fields

Comment: `@invoice.invoice_positions.build(params[:invoice][:invoice_positions_attributes])` this will help. Please provide parameters list that passed to create method from console.

Comment: @ShefaleeChaudhary it is still not working

Comment: @Swards i have added the code

Comment: please add logger by using Logger,warn or put or raise method. Try to use raise @invoice.invoice_positions.inspect before line render 'new' , if you are getting invoice positions for invoice or not.

Comment: @ShefaleeChaudhary i printed invoice.invoice_positions into console and this is what i got: #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<InvoicePosition id: nil, name: "ewfefwfew", quantity: 3, kind: "fewfwe", price: 2.0, tax: nil, invoice_id: nil>]> , so i guess there are positions in model but they are not displaying in the form

Comment: but even if i enter everything correct invoice is saving but invoice_positions arent

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.fields_for :invoice_positions do |invoice_position| %>
```

instead of

```
<% f.fields_for :invoice_positions do |invoice_position| %>
```

2.5h to get it....

--

*Rich Peck Edit*

You can clean up your `create` action a little:

```
def create
   @case    = Case.find params[:case_id]
   @invoice = @case.invoices.new invoice_params
```